# How display a text for users in the entire screen

Tags: x11, raspbian, display

I want to display a text above the user screen(as an upper layer). I know that there is solutions like xmessages that could display the text in a box, But need it to be displayed without a box on the entire screen if possible

I am running Raspbian

Is there any solution/software that could do this ?

Comment: I guess you could always just make the text really big so that it fills the screen, like `zenity --info --text '<span font="300">hello, world</span>'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`xosd`](https://sourceforge.net/projects/libxosd/), which is available in Raspbian, can display text on top of the current X screen. It takes its input from a file or from the standard input:

```
echo Hello | osd_cat -p middle -A center
```

It's an old-style X11 application so its configuration can be verbose; changing the font in particular looks like

```
echo Hello | osd_cat -p middle -A center -f '-*-lucidatypewriter-bold-*-*-*-*-240'
```

or even strictly speaking

```
echo Hello | osd_cat -p middle -A center -f '-*-lucidatypewriter-bold-*-*-*-*-240-*-*-*-*-*-*'
```

You can customise the colour, add a shadow and/or outline, change the delay, even add a progress bar.

Comment: I tried this and for some reason doesn't seem to work for me (but I remember using this like 20y ago). I don't know if it is a font issue (who has raster fonts nowadays) or the fact that I have two screens in this position: _|

Answer (score 0):

Oh , You have to choose TUI instead of GUI, because you have embedded system, dialog has a strong , for example :

```
mohsen@debian:~$ dialog --infobox "Hello world" 20 50
```

Output is :

[image]

FreeBSD uses `dialog`.

Comment: for tutorial : http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/2807